# I kept eating for 1 minute extra after sehri time ended

Tags: salat, sawm, ramadan

Assalam o Alaikum
I was doing my sehri in other room and thought sehri ending timing was 4:54 and it was actually 4:48. and i kept eating till 4:49. By brother told me that time has ended when he saw me drinking water. I immediately stopped. Is my roza still valid?

Comment: This is confusing you displayed 3 timings. Please explain do you hear the adhan? If not at which time the call (adhan) for fajr would be at your location according the prayer sheet?

Comment: I think your roza is still valid because there was no watch in the time of prophet Muhammad ( pbuh) and the difference of one minute is so little.

Comment: @Medi1Saif He thought the ending time was 4:54, but it was actually 4:58. When the time came to 4:49, he realized that the time ended one minute ago.

Comment: Upvoted this question for relevance. Where people hear the call it's clear but for the rest of the world - to what extent should we apply our chronometric precision?

Answer (score 1):

I would have liked somebody to find a published answer somewhere but I didn't find any, as well as others who have looked into your question.

There are enough aspects that speak in favour of your fast being valid:

- You had the intention to fast correctly at the time you had in mind.
- It's just a minute. Precision of time resolution in the period when the criteria were pronounced was 15 minutes at best. Even modern algorithms differ in more than 1 minute.
- As your time is  similar to mine, you are probably somewhere without a public call. Your brother has made the call and you listened.

Each criterion may be a reason that can be discussed whether that's valid on it's own.

Altogether, your fasting is so close to perfect that I don't see a reason to think that it is invalid.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question has answers on the site, but OP didn't react on any  comment asking for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Assalm o Alaikum..
I want to clear that end of sehri time has no relation with azaan... When the time of sehri ended in your region, it meant that eating and drinking is now prohibited...
So if you have done so, you have to revise your fast after Ramadan.
Jzk

Comment: I might be wrong but I think it was honest mistake on his part and his fast is still likely valid. Just like if you eat or drink by mistake while fasting; it doesn't make your fast void.

Comment: " I want to clear that end of sehri time has no relation with azaan... When the time of sehri ended in your region, it meant that eating and drinking is now prohibited" The first part is correct the second not necessarily because the limting boundary for being allowed to eat is fajr time, so if the adhan is on fajr exactly -as it should- the adhan is the limit, the so called sehri time is an innovation or safety in order to be sure that people eat before the adhan of fajr. And if a person was drinking while the adhan -as it should be- started that doesn't invalidate his fast.

Comment: These are two different conditions my dear. Forgetfulness and mistake...

Comment: Eating after sehri time considering it in time is a mistake whereas eating during your fast mistakenly is forgetfulness. There is nothing about being honest..